# How can I insert the data into the database after hitting submit?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I insert the data into the database after hitting submit, I have no idea how to connect the apartment street to the apartment id.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($apartments as $apartment)
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="{{$apartment->id}}" id="checkApt" />
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="apt[]" value="{{$apartment->id}}"id="checkApt"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="street[]" value="{{ $apartment->street }}" id="checkApt"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="aptnumber[]" value="{{ $apartment->apartment_number }}" id="checkApt"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price[]" value="{{ number_format($apartment->price, 2) }}"id="checkApt"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bedrooms[]" value="{{$apartment->bedrooms}}" id="checkApt"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bathrooms[]" value="{{$apartment->bathrooms}}"id="checkApt"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="date[]" value="{{ date('M d, Y', strtotime($apartment->created_at))}}"id="checkApt"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="area[]" value="{{ $apartment->neighborhood->neighborhood ?? '' }}"id="checkApt"></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: Are those eloquent relationships or all fields are on the same table?

Comment: Unrelated, but `id`s need to be unique: `id="checkApt"`

Comment: they are all in the same table and yes it is eloquent relationship

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
@foreach($apartments as $apartment)
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[{{$apartment->id}}]['id']" value="{{$apartment->id}}" id="checkApt" />
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="data[{{$apartment->id}}]['apt']" value="{{$apartment->id}}"id="checkApt"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[{{$apartment->id}}]['street']" value="{{ $apartment->street }}" id="checkApt"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[{{$apartment->id}}]['aptnumber']" value="{{ $apartment->apartment_number }}" id="checkApt"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[{{$apartment->id}}]['price']" value="{{ number_format($apartment->price, 2) }}"id="checkApt"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[{{$apartment->id}}]['bedrooms']" value="{{$apartment->bedrooms}}" id="checkApt"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[{{$apartment->id}}]['bathrooms']" value="{{$apartment->bathrooms}}"id="checkApt"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[{{$apartment->id}}]['date']" value="{{ date('M d, Y', strtotime($apartment->created_at))}}"id="checkApt"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[{{$apartment->id}}]['area']" value="{{ $apartment->neighborhood->neighborhood ?? '' }}"id="checkApt"></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

and in controller fetch as it `$request->data`

```
foreach($request->data as $val){
    echo 'id '.$val['id'];
    echo 'apt '.$val['apt'];
    echo 'street '.$val['street'];
    echo 'aptnumber '.$val['aptnumber'];
    echo 'price '.$val['price'];
    echo 'bedrooms '.$val['bedrooms'];
    echo 'bathrooms '.$val['bathrooms'];
    echo 'date '.$val['date'];
    echo 'area '.$val['area'];
}
```

Comment: $request->data how can i call them specifically? i'm new on laravel sorry.

Comment: `print_r($request->data)` you'll automatically understand.

Comment: i did the print_r($request->data) but when i try on the foreach($request->data as $val){ echo $val } it result to array tostring conversion error.

Comment: i did foreach loop because $val is an array and need to create another foreach, but i try foreach($request->data as $key => $value){
             foreach($value as $key => $val){}}

Comment: foreach($request->data as $key => $value){
             foreach($value as $key => $val){
echo $val['id'];
}}

resulted to illegal offspring